# How to set the timeout for cuda kernel?

Tags: cuda, timeout

I am using CUDA with Ubuntu 15.04 and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680. Now I'm testing some source code. Sometimes when the code is running too long time, I want to force stop it. But the display is not responding to me and CTRL+C isn't working (and ALT+F4). I tried to use

```
timeout 10 ./programm
```

but it's usless. Can I stop the programm (or set timeout) without rebooting?